# Confusion using parenthesis with and or

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript, but in my head the below statement should be false if I don't type 'yes' or 'no'. However, the script seems to be ignoring this, and just returning true or false depending on whether a=1 or not. Can someone exlain what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

```js
var a = 1;
var box1 = prompt("Type 'yes' or 'no' for statement to be true");
if ((box1 === "yes" || "no") && a === 1) {
  alert("Hooray!");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your condition to:

```
(box1 === "yes" || box1 === "no")
```

Your condition is evaluation to: `box1` equals "yes", or "no". Any string that is not an empty string is evaluated to `true` so "no" is converted to `true` which means your condition always evaluates to true.

```js
var a = 1;
var box1 = prompt("Type 'yes' or 'no' for statement to be true");
if ((box1 === "yes" || box1 === "no") && a === 1) {
  alert("Hooray!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to break up the condition:

```
<script>
var a = 1;
var box1 = prompt("Type 'yes' or 'no' for statement to be true");
if ((box1 === "yes" || box1 === "no") && a === 1) {
  alert("Hooray!");
} 
</script>
```

you condition is: (box1 equals "yes" OR "no") AND a equals 1
notice that "no" is a stand-alone condition.
"no" as a boolean values is true!
all strings not "" (empty) are true.
so the was: (box 1 equals "yes" OR *true*) AND a equals 1